# sorting data by date and forming graph(date vs no of occur) like google webmaster

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

my mysql table stores the date and id of the particular product
when a users access that product in mysql table it is written and it stores the details.the table structure is

id is auto-increment .product id is id of product not unique it can appear several times and time is time stamp that product was accessed by users

```
id         productid        time
1           33               3443434333
2            444             334344444
3            44               445435434
```

i want to sort out the result for any productid datewise. suppose productid 33 was accessed 1000 times in one month then i want to plot a graph datewise just like google webmaster where it shows 30 days details .for example in 1.08.12 view 30 times , 2.08.12 view 50 times etc.

which query and graph i should use so that i can show the details just like google webmaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a grouping key with `concat` from the product id and the time's date part for the per-day-counts like this ([see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc6ad/1/0)):

```
select
    count(*) value, 
    concat(date(time), '_', productid) prod 
from 
    productlog
group by 
    prod 
order by 
    prod
```

Once you get the data, there are numerous charting libraries for displaying it. Since you mentioned google's webmaster tools, you can try google's [own charting api](https://developers.google.com/chart/), or [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/), or [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) (its not free for commercial use), and probably countless other options as well.

Comment: what is prod , productlog . please explain little

Comment: It's just a name given to the result of `concat()` you can name it anything (collisions aside), you can write `concat(...) as prod` too.

Comment: please explain concat(date(time), '_', productid) output is coming empty . what is '_' executed the code in phpmyadmin

Comment: It should concatenate the date of the time column, and the productid values. Something like "2012-04-01_42" [See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc6ad/1/0)